# how to select table rows that have same value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to select row that have same code and show them by php in my page like this for example for code 333306b4af587 :

[image]

how to do this?

Comment: did you try anything ? post more details about your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately it looks like both of your examples are the same. What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no code, no help. the question lacks a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'db_inc.php';
 $code=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"select distinct uniqid,questionid from answers")        or die(mysqli_error($dbCnn));

echo "<table border='1'> ";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($code)){

$result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"select * from answers where   uniqid='$row[uniqid]' and formid=$form" )or die(mysqli_error($dbCnn));
  echo "<tr>";
  while ($responses=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<td>$responses[answer]</td>";

  }
 echo "</tr>";
}

 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use this 
You will have

```
SELECT row FROM table WHERE value1= value2;
```

If you want to pair two same value

```
SELECT row FROM Qustion1, Question2 WHERE value1 <> value2  AND value1 = value2
```